# MAUI: Issue with reading phonebook contacts

Tags: maui

I follow [this](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/10/10/getting-phone-contacts-in-xamarin-forms/) blog for reading phone book contacts from my Android and iOS devices and it was working fine on my Xamarin forms project.

Now I am migrating it to the MAUI and facing 2 problems: 1 is on `Android ContactsService` codes and the other one is on `how to read contacts data`. I have done a lot of logic and functionalities with this implementation, so changing it is a big headache for me.

**Android ContactsService**

I am getting 4 errors on this service.

```
public class ContactsService : IContactsService
{
    const string ThumbnailPrefix = "thumb";
    bool stopLoad = false;
    static TaskCompletionSource<bool> contactPermissionTcs;
    public string TAG
    {
        get
        {
            return "MainActivity";
        }
    }
    bool _isLoading = false;
    public bool IsLoading => _isLoading;

    public const int RequestContacts = 1239;
    static string[] PermissionsContact = {
        Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts
    };

    public event EventHandler<ContactEventArgs> OnContactLoaded;

    async void RequestContactsPermissions()
    {
        if (ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts)
            || ActivityCompat.ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts))
        {

            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // For example, if the request has been denied previously.

            await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Contacts Permission", "This action requires contacts permission", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            // Contact permissions have not been granted yet. Request them directly.
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, PermissionsContact, RequestContacts);
        }
    }
    public static void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        if (requestCode == ContactsService.RequestContacts)
        {
            // We have requested multiple permissions for contacts, so all of them need to be
            // checked.
            if (PermissionUtil.VerifyPermissions(grantResults))
            {
                // All required permissions have been granted, display contacts fragment.
                contactPermissionTcs.TrySetResult(true);
            }
            else
            {
                contactPermissionTcs.TrySetResult(false);
            }

        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> RequestPermissionAsync()
    {
        contactPermissionTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        // Verify that all required contact permissions have been granted.
        if (Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, Manifest.Permission.ReadContacts) != (int)Permission.Granted
            || Android.Support.V4.Content.ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, Manifest.Permission.WriteContacts) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        {
            // Contacts permissions have not been granted.
            RequestContactsPermissions();
        }
        else
        {
            // Contact permissions have been granted. 
            contactPermissionTcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }

        return await contactPermissionTcs.Task;
    }

    public async Task<IList<Contact>> RetrieveContactsAsync(CancellationToken? cancelToken = null)
    {
        stopLoad = false;

        if (!cancelToken.HasValue)
            cancelToken = CancellationToken.None;

        // We create a TaskCompletionSource of decimal
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<Contact>>();

        // Registering a lambda into the cancellationToken
        cancelToken.Value.Register(() =>
        {
            // We received a cancellation message, cancel the TaskCompletionSource.Task
            stopLoad = true;
            taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
        });

        _isLoading = true;

        var task = LoadContactsAsync();

        // Wait for the first task to finish among the two
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, taskCompletionSource.Task);
        _isLoading = false;

        return await completedTask;
    }
    
    async Task<IList<Contact>> LoadContactsAsync()
    {
        IList<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        //var hasPermission = await RequestPermissionAsync();
        //if (hasPermission)
        //{
        var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
        var ctx = Application.Context;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(uri, new string[]
            {
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoThumbnailUri
            }, null, null, $"{ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName} ASC");
            if (cursor.Count > 0)
            {
                while (cursor.MoveToNext())
                {
                    var contact = CreateContact(cursor, ctx);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.Name))
                    {
                        OnContactLoaded?.Invoke(this, new ContactEventArgs(contact));
                        contacts.Add(contact);
                    }
                    if (stopLoad)
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        // }
        return contacts;
    }

    Contact CreateContact(ICursor cursor, Context ctx)
    {
        var contactId = GetString(cursor, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id);

        var numbers = GetNumbers(ctx, contactId);
        var emails = GetEmails(ctx, contactId);

        var uri = GetString(cursor, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoThumbnailUri);
        string path = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri)))
                {
                    path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{ThumbnailPrefix}-{Guid.NewGuid()}");
                    using (var fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(fstream);
                        fstream.Close();
                    }

                    stream.Close();
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
        var contact = new Contact
        {
            Name = GetString(cursor, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName),
            Emails = emails,
            Image = path,
            PhoneNumbers = numbers,
        };

        return contact;
    }


    string[] GetNumbers(Context ctx, string contactId)
    {
        var key = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number;

        var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?",
            new[] { contactId },
            null
        );

        return ReadCursorItems(cursor, key)?.ToArray();
    }

    string[] GetEmails(Context ctx, string contactId)
    {
        var key = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.Data;

        var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri,
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?",
            new[] { contactId },
            null);

        return ReadCursorItems(cursor, key)?.ToArray();
    }

    IEnumerable<string> ReadCursorItems(ICursor cursor, string key)
    {
        while (cursor.MoveToNext())
        {
            var value = GetString(cursor, key);
            yield return value;
        }

        cursor.Close();
    }

    string GetString(ICursor cursor, string key)
    {
        return cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(key));
    }

}
```

**Errors:**

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Content' does not exist in the namespace 'Android.Support.V4' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0104  'Application' is an ambiguous reference between 'Android.App.Application' and 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Application' ListPM Caller (net7.0-android)

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0019  Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int' ListPM Caller (net7.0-android)

**How to read data**

In my Xamarin forms app I am reading the contact data like below and passing it as an argument to `App.xaml.cs`.

```
//Android
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    IContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService();
    LoadApplication(new App(contactsService));
}

//iOS
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
{
    IContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService();
    LoadApplication(new App(contactsService));
}

//App.xaml.cs
public App(IContactsService contactsService)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Utility.myContacts = contactsService;
}

//Utility.cs
public class Utility
{
    public static IContactsService myContacts;
}

//ContactsPage.xaml.cs
ContactsViewModel cvm;
public ContactsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cvm = new ContactsViewModel(Utility.myContacts);
    BindingContext = cvm;
}

//ContactsViewModel.cs
public ContactsViewModel(IContactsService contactService)
{
    //Other operations and showing it on UI
}
```

But in MAUI how can I pass the contact details from android and ios to main project?

I have uploaded a demo [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QD9X6RYA-4N3PG6uphf6oJiLdjqvJuCW/view?usp=sharing) to reproduce this issue.

**Update**

I have added the `MyContactsService` class like below, but it has a lot of errors due to the new logic.

```
namespace MyApp.Service
{
    public partial class MyContactsService
    {
        const string ThumbnailPrefix = "thumb";

        bool requestStop = false;

        public event EventHandler<ContactEventArgs> OnContactLoaded;

        bool _isLoading = false;
        public bool IsLoading => _isLoading;

        public async Task<IList<MyContact>> RetrieveContactsAsync(CancellationToken? cancelToken = null)
        {
            requestStop = false;

            if (!cancelToken.HasValue)
                cancelToken = CancellationToken.None;

            // We create a TaskCompletionSource of decimal
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IList<MyContact>>();

            // Registering a lambda into the cancellationToken
            cancelToken.Value.Register(() =>
            {
                // We received a cancellation message, cancel the TaskCompletionSource.Task
                requestStop = true;
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetCanceled();
            });

            _isLoading = true;

            var task = LoadContactsAsync();

            // Wait for the first task to finish among the two
            var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, taskCompletionSource.Task);
            _isLoading = false;

            return await completedTask;

        }

        public async Task<bool> RequestPermissionAsync()
        {
            var status = CNContactStore.GetAuthorizationStatus(CNEntityType.Contacts);

            Tuple<bool, NSError> authotization = new Tuple<bool, NSError>(status == CNAuthorizationStatus.Authorized, null);

            if (status == CNAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined)
            {
                using (var store = new CNContactStore())
                {
                    authotization = await store.RequestAccessAsync(CNEntityType.Contacts);
                }
            }
            return authotization.Item1;

        }

        public partial async Task<List<MyContact>> GetContactsAsync()
        {
            IList<MyContact> contacts = new List<MyContact>();
            var hasPermission = await RequestPermissionAsync();
            if (hasPermission)
            {

                NSError error = null;
                var keysToFetch = new[] { CNContactKey.PhoneNumbers, CNContactKey.GivenName, CNContactKey.FamilyName, CNContactKey.EmailAddresses, CNContactKey.ImageDataAvailable, CNContactKey.ThumbnailImageData };

                var request = new CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch);
                request.SortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.GivenName;

                using (var store = new CNContactStore())
                {
                    var result = store.EnumerateContacts(request, out error, new CNContactStoreListContactsHandler((CNContact c, ref bool stop) =>
                    {

                        string path = null;
                        if (c.ImageDataAvailable)
                        {
                            path = path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{ThumbnailPrefix}-{Guid.NewGuid()}");

                            if (!File.Exists(path))
                            {
                                var imageData = c.ThumbnailImageData;
                                imageData?.Save(path, true);


                            }
                        }

                        var contact = new MyContact()
                        {
                            Name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.FamilyName) ? c.GivenName : $"{c.GivenName} {c.FamilyName}",
                            Image = path,
                            PhoneNumbers = c.PhoneNumbers?.Select(p => p?.Value?.StringValue).ToArray(),
                            Emails = c.EmailAddresses?.Select(p => p?.Value?.ToString()).ToArray(),

                        };

                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.Name))
                        {
                            //OnContactLoaded?.Invoke(this, new ContactEventArgs(contact));
                            contacts.Add(contact);
                        }

                        stop = requestStop;

                    }));
                }
            }
            return contacts;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for the first two errors, hover over the error in the code window and right click and select "Suggested Fixes".  For the third, this is a basic C# error, you need to specify the namespace to eliminate the ambiguity.  For the fourth, I have no idea which line is causing it so its difficult to say how to fix it.  All of these error types are covered in the C# docs.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/contacts?tabs=android

Comment: @Jason For the first 2 errors, there is no fixes suggesting, only suggesting to create a content class in new file. I have removed the `using Android.App` namespace for resolving the third error. But at that time getting another error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEK4J.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Previously I am passing contactsService object as an argument to
> App.xaml.cs from MainActivity and AppDelegate. But in MAUI no calls to
> App.xaml.cs.

We don't need to pass the returned value from the local platform to the shared platform, we can get the returned contacts list by [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0) directly.

I think there are a couple of problems with the way you implement it on `Maui`.

Based on the code you shared, I achieved this function with [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0).

You can refer to the following code:

1.To distinguish class `Contact` of system, I created a class `MyContact.cs`

```
namespace MauiGetContactsApp.Models
{
    public class MyContact
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string[] Emails { get; set; }
        public string[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2.create a partial class `MyContactsService.cs` and add a partial method `GetContacts()`.Then we can get the contacts list by the returned value of  method `GetContacts()`:

```
namespace MauiGetContactsApp.Services
{
    public partial class MyContactsService
    {
        public partial List<MyContact> GetContacts();

    }
}
```

3.On platform `Android`,implement partial method `GetContacts()`. I copied the read contacts methods from your demo. And I removed the request permission on android platform. We just need to request permission on shared platform.

```
//namespace MauiGetContactsApp.Platforms.Android
namespace MauiGetContactsApp.Services
{
    public partial class MyContactsService
    {
        const string ThumbnailPrefix = "thumb";

        List<MyContact> contactList;


        public partial List<MyContact> GetContacts()
        {
           // contactList = new List<MyContact>();

            FillContacts();


            return contactList;
        }

        void FillContacts()
        {
            var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

            string[] projection = {
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoId,
            };


            var ctx = Android.App.Application.Context;    

            var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(uri, new string[]
{
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoThumbnailUri
}, null, null, $"{ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName} ASC");

            contactList = new List<MyContact>();

            if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {  
                    var contact = CreateContact(cursor, ctx);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.DisplayName))
                    {
                        contactList.Add(contact);
                    }
                } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
            }
        }


        MyContact CreateContact(ICursor cursor, Context ctx)
        {
            var contactId = GetString(cursor, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id);

            var numbers = GetNumbers(ctx, contactId);
            var emails = GetEmails(ctx, contactId);

            var uri = GetString(cursor, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.PhotoThumbnailUri);
            string path = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var stream = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(uri)))
                    {
                        path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{ThumbnailPrefix}-{Guid.NewGuid()}");
                        using (var fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            stream.CopyTo(fstream);
                            fstream.Close();
                        }

                        stream.Close();
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }

            }
            var contact = new MyContact
            {
                DisplayName = GetString(cursor, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName),
                Emails = emails,
                Image = path,
                PhoneNumbers = numbers,
            };

            return contact;
        }


        string[] GetNumbers(Context ctx, string contactId)
        {
            var key = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number;

            var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?",
                new[] { contactId },
                null
            );

            return ReadCursorItems(cursor, key)?.ToArray();
        }

        string[] GetEmails(Context ctx, string contactId)
        {
            var key = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.Data;

            var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ContentUri,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.InterfaceConsts.ContactId + " = ?",
                new[] { contactId },
                null);

            return ReadCursorItems(cursor, key)?.ToArray();
        }

        IEnumerable<string> ReadCursorItems(ICursor cursor, string key)
        {
            while (cursor.MoveToNext())
            {
                var value = GetString(cursor, key);
                yield return value;
            }

            cursor.Close();
        }

        string GetString(ICursor cursor, string key)
        {
            return cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(key));
        }
    }
}
```

4.On shared platform, I added a button to trigger the function of reading contacts. And before reading contacts,we need to check and request the `ContactsRead` permission.

```
using MauiGetContactsApp.Models;
using Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Communication;
using MyContactsService = MauiGetContactsApp.Services.MyContactsService;

namespace MauiGetContactsApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        List<MyContact> contacts;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            contacts= new List<MyContact>();
        }

        private async void Btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          await  RequestContactPermission();
        }


        async Task RequestContactPermission()
        {
            var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;
            {
                status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();

                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    // get cotacts List
                    getContacts();
                    return;
                }

                if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.ContactsRead>())
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "BECAUSE!!!", "OK");
                }

                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();

            }


            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Permission required",
                    "Read Contacts permission is required for calling. " +
                    "We just want to do a test.", "OK");

            else if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                getContacts();

            }
        }

        public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestPhonePermission()
        {
            PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                return status;

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
            {
                // Prompt the user to turn on in settings
                // On iOS once a permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
                return status;
            }

            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.ContactsRead>())
            {
                // Prompt the user with additional information as to why the permission is needed

                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Need permission", "We need the Phone permission", "Ok");
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                getContacts();

            }
            else
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Permission required",
                      "Read Contacts permission is required for read contacts " +
                      "We just want to test", "OK");

            }

            return status;
        }


        public void getContacts() {

            var service = new MyContactsService();
            contacts = service.GetContacts();


            foreach (var contact in contacts)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("------> " + contact.DisplayName ) ;

                foreach (var phoneNumber in contact.PhoneNumbers) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("name = " + phoneNumber );
                }

                foreach (var email in contact.Emails) {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Email = " + email);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1.Remember to add `ContactsRead` permission on `AndroidManifest.xaml`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

2.On iOS platform,the steps are the same. You just need to copy the code that reads contacts on the iOS platform to the method `GetContacts();` implemented on iOS.

3.Remember to keep the namespace for `MyContactsService.cs` on individual platform(`Android` and `iOS`) to be consistent with the namespace of `MyContactsService.cs` on shared platform.

4.The whole file struct of my demo is:

[image]

**Update:**

On iOS, since we have checked and requested permission on shared platform, so we don't need to add the code requesting permission on iOS platform.

Please refer to the following code:

```
namespace MauiGetContactsApp.Services
{
    public partial  class MyContactsService
    {
        const string ThumbnailPrefix = "thumb";

        List<MyContact> contacts = new List<MyContact>();

        public partial List<MyContact> GetContacts()
        {
            NSError error = null;
            var keysToFetch = new[] { CNContactKey.PhoneNumbers, CNContactKey.GivenName, CNContactKey.FamilyName, CNContactKey.EmailAddresses, CNContactKey.ImageDataAvailable, CNContactKey.ThumbnailImageData };

            var request = new CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch);
            request.SortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.GivenName;

            using (var store = new CNContactStore())
            {
                var result = store.EnumerateContacts(request, out error, new CNContactStoreListContactsHandler((CNContact c, ref bool stop) =>
                {

                    string path = null;
                    if (c.ImageDataAvailable)
                    {
                        path = path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{ThumbnailPrefix}-{Guid.NewGuid()}");

                        if (!File.Exists(path))
                        {
                            var imageData = c.ThumbnailImageData;
                            imageData?.Save(path, true);


                        }
                    }

                    var contact = new MyContact()
                    {
                        DisplayName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.FamilyName) ? c.GivenName : $"{c.GivenName} {c.FamilyName}",
                        Image = path,
                        PhoneNumbers = c.PhoneNumbers?.Select(p => p?.Value?.StringValue).ToArray(),
                        Emails = c.EmailAddresses?.Select(p => p?.Value?.ToString()).ToArray(),

                    };

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contact.DisplayName))
                    {
                        contacts.Add(contact);
                    }


                }));
            }

            return contacts;
        }
     }
}
```

Remember to add the following code to file `Info.plist`

```
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need this permission...</string>
```

Comment: I am getting below error on MyContactsService class: Partial method must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sei0B.png

Comment: It's the same on my side, if your other code is correct, you can ignore this problem and deploy the code directly to your device.

Comment: Do we need any additional set up for asking contacts permission? I am getting this exception: `System.NullReferenceException: The current Activity can not be detected. Ensure that you have called Init in your Activity or Application class.` on the line `if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.ContactsRead>())`

Comment: I tried adding `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` and `Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);` on `MainActivity`, but no luck.

Comment: You don't need to this on android platform.  Have you tried my code `await  RequestContactPermission();`?

Comment: The code I posted on my answer could work normally on my app. You don't need to add extra code. I could request permission and read the contacts on my side.

Comment: One problem, one thread. For the new problem, you can create a new thread. We are all willing to help you.  :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528534/maui-how-to-call-a-long-running-task-or-multiple-long-running-tasks-in-maui

Comment: `I am getting below error on MyContactsService class: Partial method must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers`: This issue not affected the android part, but it is showing as an error in iOS and I can't build the app.

Comment: Have you added the necessary code on iOS platform?

Comment: I added it now, but due to the new logic changes I don't know how to update the code. It has a lot of errors, could you please check and share the code for iOS `MyContactsService` class? I have added it on question now.

Comment: Please check my updated reply at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I added that and able to run on android device. But on iOS device I can't run it due to the below errors. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxynl.png

Comment: Any solution for the ios platform?

Comment: The code I posted could work properly on my iOS device. You can recheck if you have kept the namespace for `MyContactsService.cs` on individual platform(Android and iOS) to be consistent with the namespace of `MyContactsService.cs `on shared platform.

Comment: Besides, remember to add `NSContactsUsageDescription` to file `Info.plist` for iOS.

Comment: The `namesapces` are same and added `NSContactsUsageDescription`. Is there any chance this is due to the xcode version? I am using an older version?

Comment: Can you ignore this log and deploy it directly to your phone?