# MAUI: How to call a long running task or multiple long running tasks in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui

I have below 2 scenarios:

1. I need to call around 7 different REST APIs from my home page. Currently after one API call I call the next one and again at the end calling the next one. Due to this my app is hang and slow. Below is my sample code:

```
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        APICall1();
    }

    public async void APICall1()
    {
        APICall2();
    }

    public async void APICall2()
    {
        APICall3();
    }
```

2. I am fetching my device phone-book contacts and showing it on my UI. This also taking a lot of time and the app is hang and slow. Sometimes the app is closing because of this issue.

I tried calling the fetch contacts function from `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` like below, but no luck.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    await RequestContactPermission();
});
```

I also found use `Task.Run` as a solution for this issue. But I didn't get how to use it. So how can I call this kind of long running tasks without affecting the app performance?

Comment: I have some advice for you, not direct solution but you can go through it. Firstly you can add some loading bar on your screen. You can set loading bar's visibility false after all apicalls are done.  I hope you can fix.

Comment: @MertAltiparmak I initially did that, but the users needs to wait a long time to finish the progress bar.

Comment: You can try to call the method on another thread. Please check this [Task.Run Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-8.0).

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Is it possible to set the itemsource value if we call it from Task.Run? For my second scenario, I need to load the phonebook contacts and need to show it on the UI. But I get an exception: `Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Is Task.Run methods are executing on main thread or background thread?

Comment: Any action involving the user interface must be done in the main or UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use Task.Run

```
await Task.Run(() => ApiCall1());
```

Your ApiCalls are dependent on each other so it will take long anyway. With task run you run the action in another thread and can at least do other stuff on the MainThread.
Optimal would be a result and cancellation token if the call failed for some reason.

Comment: Sometimes getting below exception, any idea about that: `Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`